# Why function execution is completed before I click on OK button in an Alert android?

Tags: android

When I want to retrieve a value from an Alert box in android, it returns before I click on OK button.

here is the function I made:

```
public String enterSecretCode(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Secret Code");
    alert.setMessage("Enter your 5 digit Secret Code to Encode!");

 // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});
    input.setHint("XXXXX");
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            code = input.getText().toString();
            // Do something with value!
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });

    alert.show();

    return code;
}
```

and here is the function call which I am trying to excuse on a button click:

```
String secretCode = enterSecretCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

`show()` is not a blocking call. You need to rewrite your code to process your results as part of the positive button `onClick()` method, rather than having this method return some value.

Comment: can you please provide me a sample? Actually I want to retrieve value in the String secretCode for some scenario!

Comment: @JahanzaibSuleman: You already have the sample. If you look at your code, you will see `// Do something with value!`. Replace that with what you want to do with the value.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have solved the problem with your hint! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use an Interface:

Create a new Class called AlertInterface

```
public class AlertInterface {

Context context;
Receiver receiver;

public AlertInterface(Context context, Receiver receiver)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.receiver=receiver;
}

public void enterSecretCode()
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);

    alert.setTitle("Secret Code");
    alert.setMessage("Enter your 5 digit Secret Code to Encode!");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this.context);
    input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});
    input.setHint("XXXXX");
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String code = input.getText().toString();
            receiver.onLoad(code);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}

public interface Receiver{
    void onLoad(String code);
}
```

}

For calling this Class add this in your Activity:

```
 AlertInterface aux=new AlertInterface(MainActivity.this, new AlertInterface.Receiver() {
        public void onLoad(String code) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Secret code entered: "+code,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    aux.enterSecretCode();
```

The result will receive in onLoad implement method in the Activity.